# Pasar valor de tabla a jquery

Tags: jquery

Tengo una tabla con datos de usuario y quiero obtener el id del usuario a través de data-value para luego pasarlo a otro ajax

variables: id, nombre.
De la siguiente manera obtengo los datos del usuario (todo bien hasta aqui).

```
$("#searchResult").append("<tr data-value='"+id+"'><td>"+nombre+"</td></tr>");
```

Al hacer click en uno de los resultados obtenidos en la tabla anterior, quiero tomar el valor del id para usarlo en otra consulta

```
$("#searchResult tr value").bind("click",function(){
  setText(this);
});
```

el problema es que no estoy logrando obtener el dato mediante  $("#searchResult tr value"). Busqué mas información y me dice que implemente data.(). Pero no sé como usarlo sin interrumpir la función click.

Soy aprendiz, agradezco cualquier aporte.

Comment: ¿Obtienes algo o no pasa nada cuando haces eso sobre un value? Es decir, no sale nada en  consola aunque le metas un console.log dentro de la función del click, etc... ¿cierto?

Comment: Si meto un  console.log(this); dentro de la funcion click, no pasa nada. En el html, si  me está trayendo el id en  data-value correctamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema parece ser debido a que cuando cargas el documento haces esto:

```
$("#searchResult tr value").bind("click",function(){
  setText(this);
});
```

pero en ese momento aun no existen los elementos que después vas a crear con esto:

```
$("#searchResult").append("<tr data-value='"+id+"'><td>"+nombre+"</td></tr>");
```

por lo tanto quedan excluidos de esa escucha del evento `click` sobre ellos, pues no existían durante la carga inicial del documento.

Hay varias soluciones posibles, pero yo me decanto por esta (suponiendo que no existan más tablas y que ese `append` lo hace en todas las filas `<tr>` contenidas en el elemento con `id="searchResult"`, sino algunas pulsaciones te podrian dar error por no tener ese atributo `data-value`):

```
$("#searchResult").on("click","tr", function(event){
  setText($(this).attr('data-value'));
});
```

El método [`bind()`](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) está obsoleto desde la version 3 de jquery, y carece de la [delegación de eventos](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) que sí tiene el método `on()`.

**Nota:**  Si tienes varias tablas o distintas filas dentro del elemento con id `searchResult` donde no quieras ejecutar esa función `setText` te recomiendo que uses clases en el `tr` para diferenciarlos y modifiques el selector de la función `on()` acorde con ello.

Answer (score 1):

El selector que pones tecnicamente dice que busque un id searchResult dentro contenga un tag tr y dentro un tag value, el cual no existe, si lo que buscas es obtener el valor del data probablemente el selector deberia de ir al tr

```
$("#searchResult tr").bind("click",function(){
  var id = this.dataset.value;
  ...
});
```

Y ya con el valor ya continuas con lo que necesites.

Tambien lo puedes definir de la siguiente manera:

```
$("body").on("click","#searchResult tr",function(){
   var id = this.dataset.value;
   ...
});
```